# Get music file in windows phone 8.1 runtime too slow

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working with music in music library in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime. But have a problem. It's too slow. In Windows Phone 8.0 or 8.0 Silverlight, when I used Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media, it was very fast. In WP 8.1 runtime, I can't use XNA and I have to use KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.
For example:

```
App.listMusicFiles = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);

for (int i = 0; i < App.listMusicFiles.Count; i++)
{
    MusicProperties musicProperties = await App.listMusicFiles[i].Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
App.listSongs.Add(new DeviceSongModel(i, musicProperties.Title, musicProperties.Artist, App.listMusicFiles[i].Path,     App.listMusicFiles[i].ContentType, musicProperties.Album, musicProperties.Duration.Ticks, ""));

}
```

It very, very slow. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are seeing is probably because of this line here:

```
await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
```

Under the covers it is walking through [every music file on the entire device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx), creating an in-memory representation of each file, and marshalling the representation back to your app's process.

The better way to do this is to only grab a fixed size batch of files at a time using `await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName,index,batchSize);`. This will cap the numbers of files that are returned. You can then process the returned files while in the background requesting the next batch.

Comment: Thank Adam! But i think problem is in for loop to get music info. GetFilesAsync() get all music file very fast!

Comment: Is there any faster way to retrieve musicProperties?